# Just switched to JRuby, having some trouble getting rails started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I just installed JRuby on my mac using the following command:

```
rvm install jruby-1.6.4
```

And then installed rails using the following command:

```
rvmsudo gem install rails
```

When I try to start my server, I get the following error:

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x0 rip=0x10fc4c5f9
[1]    14068 segmentation fault  rails server
```

Has anyone seen this before? What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a jruby error. Did you do an 'rvm use jruby-1.6.4' or set it as the default?

Comment: Yes I did both of those things.

Comment: Somehow you're still getting MRI ruby when executing the `rails` command. What happens when you gem install rails (no rvmsudo)?